# Python PYQT5 Draggable Window/Tools

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I can't find the term for it. But What I am looking for is help on how does do a Window that consists of multiple widgets.
Many software consists of this feature where you could drag and drop a window/tool window.
It drags and drop in a form of layouts and it's resizeable by dragging.
Image 1 is where you could drag and drop.
Image 2 is the entire thing. where the layout is fluid and can be resized.
My PYQT5 mainwindow consists of the QtabWindows and QlistWidgets.
Tabs should be able to split/join and create new layouts as such in the picture.
All help is greated appreciated
[image]
[image]

Comment: Use [QDockWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html) and a QMainWindow with [`addDockWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#addDockWidget) and related functions.

Comment: Sorry. I'm quite new to PYQT5 and Python. Related functions? like the drag and drop function that can be found?

Comment: I don't mean to kill your hopes, but, be aware, Qt is a *huge* toolkit that has a quite peculiar learning curve. It might seem easy at the beginning, but it's composed of thousands classes and hundreds of thousands functions. Don't get me wrong: it's a *wonderful*, extremely powerful and incredibly extensible toolkit. But all that has its toll: great power, great responsibility, etc. Be patient, start gradually. What you're asking is not impossible, but it also doesn't come "out of the box". I suggest you to start by playing around with Designer to begin. And, then, there's the documentation.

Comment: And with "there's the documentation" I seriously mean that. Qt has one of the *best* documentation I've ever seen (it's not perfect, obviously, it has its quirks, but, as said, we're talking about hundreds of thousands of functions and dozens of "generic" frameworks). Read it, use search tools, learn from it, then read it again. Then look for inherited classes and read about reimplemented functions. Look for tutorials and alternate explanations. Test yourself, create random examples to understand how something works, how to break it and then fix it again. Learn to *learn*. And good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the Input. I'll give it a try and experiment. Yea With how far I've come. It's really a great toolkit. I do agree with the learning curves as i do experience certain issues and things. I only started PYQT5 around april/may.

Comment: Well, I *seriously* started with it around 2015 and I've been practicing/working/playing/studying/struggling (but mostly) enjoying it almost every other day since then. Just yesterday I found out something I didn't knew yet. That might seem odd and quite depressing, but I actually find it wonderful: you never end to learn something new! (obviously, I don't mean that Qt is *perfect*, as it certainly is ***not***; it has its drawbacks, oddities and annoying issues, but all the rest is usually so overwhelmingly fun, coherent and *consistent* that it just overshadows those "cons" by many lengths)

Comment: Honestly I hated Python. That's until my job requires me to learn it. So I actually had fun with python so far. But i am struggling with PYQT5 not the base coding as I started out with C#